# Getting OutOfMemoryError while launching mobile application using appium

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

I am trying to automate a mobile app, and while I execute the test class, I get java OutOfMemoryError.

The app launches successfully but after that there are no logs in appium server, but in eclipse console I get the below error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintWriter.print(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Unknown Source)
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the RAM size of your system?

Comment: This gives us little information to go on. There are plenty of variables, such as RAM size of the system (as Vinod has suggested), the RAM size of your JVM, what's actually going on in the code, and what the program is even doing. I'd suggest following that stack trace and giving us concise excerpts of your code where it will help us the best.